# after clicking on button1 should be switched on and off checkBox the time interval

Tags: c#, checkbox

Can you help? In C#, after clicking on button1, checkBoxWMVFile (the time interval) 
should be switched on and off.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (timercheckbox.Enabled == true)
    {
        timercheckbox = new Timer();
        timercheckbox.Start();
        timercheckbox.Interval = 10000; // 10 second

        if(timercheckbox.Enabled)
        {
            timercheckbox.Start();
            checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            timercheckbox.Stop();
            checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tired?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Please provide more information about your specific problem, instead of asking for a complete solution!

Comment: It's nearly impossible to understand your question. Please clarify *what, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?*

Comment: To respond to timer timeout you need to add timeout handler `timercheckbox.Elapsed += timercheckbox_Elapsed;` If you clarify your question I might be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I use the app medialooks videomixer SDK and I wont inplement automatic video recording after 1 hour. so I want to checkboxfileWMV turned on every hour and turned off

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need something like this

```
private Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = 10000;
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            if(_timer.Enabled)
                _timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
            if (!_timer.Enabled)
                _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I entered the code into your App and button1 pressed for 10 seconds to display the error message:
  throw new NotImplementedException ();
The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: Martin, you haven't read the code @steavy posted before pasting it into your project, have you? Look at the _timer_Tick method.

Comment: martin, you have to implement _timer_Tick method. I left there exception since I don`t know exactly what are you doing in you application. Maby you will need to reset timer in this method, but maby you need some extra logic there so it is up to you.

Comment: Steavy Hi, Hi Verdana! I am not a programmer, I just wanted to simplify my work ... App videomixer recording video from camcorder. And I want to break the record every hour and to create a separate video file. I thought we use a system Thraed.sleep but it does not work. The only option is time interval but do not know about it .... The last attempt ... How do I implement _timer_Tick method. Just select Toolbox in Timer and turn it into _Timer? Because I tried it and nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, you have to reverse the logic i.e.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkBoxWMVFile.Checked == false)//if the textbox is not checked
    {
        if (timercheckbox == null)//If this is the first time
        {
            timercheckbox = new Timer();//Create a timer
            timercheckbox.Interval = 10000; // Set the interval, before starting it.
            timercheckbox.Start();//Start it
        }
        else timercheckbox.Start();//If it is not the first time, just start it
        checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = true;//Check the checkbox
    }
    else//the checkbox is checked
    {
       timercheckbox.Stop();//Stop the timer
       checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = false;//Uncheck the checkbox
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ThunderGr. I tried your code. After clicking on button1, the recording turned on after 10 seconds but it still / video recording is still /. Anything else should be?

Comment: For Codesparkle: Hi, Sorry. App. Videomixer recorded video by clicking on checkboxfileWMV and video is recorded all Time. I want to be video recorded every 1 hour when I click on button1. I have saved the video for 24 hours divided by 1 hour

Comment: The code is a sample for the button1_click event. You have to define the actions you want to do, after the time elapses in the timer event, as demonstrated by steavy. One easy way I can think that may solve your problem, would be to call the button1_click event from within the timer event.

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly:

```
// InitializeComponent        
this.timercheckbox.Interval = 5000;
this.timercheckbox.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timercheckbox_Tick);

private void timercheckbox_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = false;
    checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( timercheckbox.Enabled == true )
    {            
        timercheckbox.Enabled = false;
        button1.Text = "Start Auto save";
    }
    else
    {
        timercheckbox.Interval = (int)numericChnageTime.Value;
        timercheckbox.Enabled = true;
        checkBoxWMVFile.Checked = true;
        button1.Text = "Stop Auto save";
    }
}
```